# Is there a way in MATLAB to tell if a name is the name of a callable?

Tags: matlab, predicate, callable

At the [doc page for `is*` functions](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/is.html), I don't see any `isfunc`, `isfunction`, `iscallable` or similar. Is there really no way to make this type of test in MATLAB?

Comment: You probably want to know if a variable `f` is a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html). For that you can use `isa(f, 'function_handle')`